# Equation with infinitely many solutions

Tags: functions

Find all solutions to the equation sin(2x) cos(2x) = 1/2 that are in the interval [0,16]. Give all your answers as exact values, and state the number of solutions.

Comment: Sin(2x)=2Sin(x)Cos(x)

Comment: Perhaps you meant to ask this on [math.se]? Otherwise, `Solve[Sin[2 x] Cos[2 x] == 1/2]` seems to work just fine.

Answer (score 0):

The solutions can be found according to:

```
sol = DeleteDuplicates[Solve[{Sin[2 x] Cos[2 x] == 1/2, 0 <= x <= 16}, x]]
```

and the length by:

```
Length[sol]
```

all answers:

```
\[Pi]-ArcTan[1-Sqrt[2]]
2 \[Pi]-ArcTan[1-Sqrt[2]]
3 \[Pi]-ArcTan[1-Sqrt[2]]
4 \[Pi]-ArcTan[1-Sqrt[2]]
-ArcTan[1-Sqrt[2]]
\[Pi]-ArcTan[1+Sqrt[2]]
2 \[Pi]-ArcTan[1+Sqrt[2]]
3 \[Pi]-ArcTan[1+Sqrt[2]]
4 \[Pi]-ArcTan[1+Sqrt[2]]
5 \[Pi]-ArcTan[1+Sqrt[2]]
```

Comment: Using `FullSimplify` will provide much cleaner results.

Answer (score 0):

$\sin(2x)\cos(2x)=\frac{1}{2}$

$2\sin(2x)\cos(2x)=1$. Double identity gives $\sin(4x)=1$.

Let $4x=t$.   We get $\sin(t)=1$ and $t=\frac{\pi}{2}+2\pi k, \quad   k\in\mathbb{Z}$.

Thus, we have $x=\frac{\pi+4\pi k}{8}$.

$x\in[0,16]$ implies $k\in[0,9]$

> $x=\left\{\frac{\pi }{8},\frac{5 \pi }{8},\frac{9 \pi }{8},\frac{13 \pi }{8},\frac{17 \pi }{8},\frac{21 \pi }{8},\frac{25 \pi }{8},\frac{29 \pi
>    }{8},\frac{33 \pi }{8},\frac{37 \pi }{8}\right\}$